# PCA plots of only one principal component

Tags: r, plot

I have environmental transect data for three environmental variables. I have performed a PCA in R on my three environmental variables. I would like to plot my points (sites on my transect) along a single principal compoent. If I use the `plot()` function  in R it generates a 2d biplot.

How do I create a 1D plot of my PCA?

Here is what I have done:

```
pca1= princomp(~ X250 + X500 + shear, data=data, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
plot(pca1)
```

Answer (score 6):

> How do I create a 1D plot of my PCA?

You can use the `linestack()` function in the **vegan** package for a plot of a single PCA axis (others have pointed out the error that led to you only getting a single component in this case).

E.g.:

```
library("vegan")
data(dune)

## fit PCA
pca <- rda(dune, scale = TRUE)

## 1D plot
linestack(scores(pca, choices = 1, display = "species"))
linestack(scores(pca, choices = 1, display = "sites"), side = "left", add = TRUE)
```

which gives

[image]

The argument `choices` selects the dimension you wish to plot. In the above example this was component `1`, but any of the components can be selected this way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `vegan::ordiplot()` knows `prcomp` and `princomp` results and will produce a `linestack` graph if only one axis is requested. This should work:

```
pca1 <- princomp(~ X250 + X500 + shear, data=data, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
ordiplot(pca1, choices = 1)
```

The scaling of row and column scores can be odd with respect to each other, though (`rda` scales more equally).